# Python: all possible combinations of list items Set

Tags: python

There is a dictionary

```
ages = {
    "45-64": 0.025671085927991368,
    "65+": 0.0018149553095834115,
    "35-44": 0.040190728404658656,
    "18-24": 0.37733412203543515,
    "13-17": 0.35014384408604765,
    "25-34": 0.20484526423628374
   }
```

From which I need to take the keys (the list of age groups) "45-64", "65+", "35-44", "18-24", "13-17", "25-34". How can get from it all possible unique combinations whose elements are separated by the age line:
Like this:

```
age18-24age35-44
age13-17age25-34age35-44age65-
age18-24age35-44
age13-17age25-34age45-54age65-
age13-17age18-24age25-34age55-64age65-
....
....
```

Sorting order is not important, the most important is uniqueness. Those. age18-24age35-44 and age35-44age18-24 is a duplicate, because the sum of their values ​​will be the same.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: do you need `list(ages.keys())` ??

Comment: `age18-24age35-44,
 age13-17age25-34age35-44age65-, age18-24age35-44, 
age13-17age25-34age45-54age65-, 
age13-17age18-24age25-34age55-64age65-, 
....
....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations
from pprint import pprint
pprint([''.join(map('age'.__add__, a)) for i in range(2, len(ages) + 1) for a in combinations(ages, i)])
```

This outputs:

```
['age45-64age65+',
 'age45-64age35-44',
 'age45-64age18-24',
 'age45-64age13-17',
 'age45-64age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44',
 'age65+age18-24',
 'age65+age13-17',
 'age65+age25-34',
 'age35-44age18-24',
 'age35-44age13-17',
 'age35-44age25-34',
 'age18-24age13-17',
 'age18-24age25-34',
 'age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24',
 'age45-64age65+age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24',
 'age45-64age35-44age13-17',
 'age45-64age35-44age25-34',
 'age45-64age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24',
 'age65+age35-44age13-17',
 'age65+age35-44age25-34',
 'age65+age18-24age13-17',
 'age65+age18-24age25-34',
 'age65+age13-17age25-34',
 'age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.product` to do this

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
l = ages.keys()
l2 = list(chain(*[['age'.join(('',)+c) for c in combinations(l,i)] for i in range(2, len(l))]))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(l2)
```

**Output**

```
['age45-64age65+',
 'age45-64age35-44',
 'age45-64age18-24',
 'age45-64age13-17',
 'age45-64age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44',
 'age65+age18-24',
 'age65+age13-17',
 'age65+age25-34',
 'age35-44age18-24',
 'age35-44age13-17',
 'age35-44age25-34',
 'age18-24age13-17',
 'age18-24age25-34',
 'age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24',
 'age45-64age65+age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24',
 'age45-64age35-44age13-17',
 'age45-64age35-44age25-34',
 'age45-64age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24',
 'age65+age35-44age13-17',
 'age65+age35-44age25-34',
 'age65+age18-24age13-17',
 'age65+age18-24age25-34',
 'age65+age13-17age25-34',
 'age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age18-24age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age35-44age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age65+age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age45-64age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34',
 'age65+age35-44age18-24age13-17age25-34']
```